# Animator equivilant to of applyTransformation in new Animation

Tags: android, android-animation, objectanimator

I have some code that is using `new Animation()` it has a method `applyTransformation` that allows you to create a custom animation.

I've created a `new Animator()` but can not figure where to put the custom animation.

How do I create a custom animation using `Animator`?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
    ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0,100);
    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
           Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
           Log.v(TAG, String.valueOf(value));
        }
    });
    anim.setDuration(500);
    anim.start();
```